# How can I do this programmatically?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how can I do this programmatically:

```
var a={a:"a",b:"b"};
return a.a;
         |
        I want to change this programmatically, how can I do that?
```

without using `eval()`?

Comment: give us a test case please. What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dynamically access object properties, you need to invoke the *bracket notation* form. Like

```
function foo( prop ) {
    var a = {a:'a', b: 'b'};

    return a[ prop ];
}

foo('b'); // returns 'b'
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I can only use `[]` when it's an array.

Answer (score 5):

Use `a[v]` where `v` is a variable those value is either `'a'` or `'b'`.